# Wordpress roots/sage installation options not working

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, wordpress-theming, roots-sage

I have install sage on my wordpress, but there no choice for selecting options that sage [docs](https://github.com/roots/sage) says

> During theme installation you will have the options to:
>
> - Update theme headers (theme name, description, author, etc.)
> - Select a CSS framework (Bootstrap, Foundation, Tachyons, none)
> - Add Font Awesome
> - Configure Browsersync (path to theme, local development URL)

```
C:\php7\htdocs\blog\wp-content\themes>composer create-project roots/sage foundat
ion 8.5.3
Installing roots/sage (8.5.3)
  - Installing roots/sage (8.5.3): Loading from cache
Created project in foundation
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing composer/installers (v1.4.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

I success activate the foundation theme on wordpress dashboard. Is I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing sage 9 there is still no choice for selecting options because TTY mode is not supported on Windows platforms.

To work around it, run these commands from within your theme directory:

```
./vendor/bin/sage meta
./vendor/bin/sage config
./vendor/bin/sage preset
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the docs for sage 9.x but installing 8.5.3 which is a complete different setup and doesnt have the features mentioned above. Sage 9 can only be installed when running PHP 7.x and up.

If you just use the same composer command without the version number you shouls get the latest version.